# Regexp that matches strings that have 2n+2 numbers where n is an integer; so " this is a match 123456!" and "this is not 1!"

Tags: regex

Apologies; I'm new to Regex; is it possible to develop an expression that will match strings that has a list of adjacent numbers (that don't have to be ordered) where the count of the numbers equals the expression 2n+2? So " asdasd 02" would match because when n is 0, 2*0+2=2; similarly "asdasd 098675asas" would match because when n is 2, the 2*2+2 = 6 and the string has 6 numbers. Sorry for any clumsy language!

Comment: What have you tried? Which language are you using? This seems broad/unclear.

Comment: `2n+2`?  So....`3n`?  Yeah, this is wildly unclear.

Comment: Probably as easy a regex as `(\d\d)+`

Comment: Apologies; I'm new to Regex; is it possible to develop an expression that will match strings that have numbers that meet the following criteria:

Comment: @Ottomann before you continue, add this information to your question, not in comments.

Comment: Apologies; I'm new to Regex; is it possible to develop an expression that will match strings that has a list of adjacent numbers (that don't have to be ordered) where the count of the numbers equals the expression 2n+2? So " asdasd 02" would match because when n is 0, 2*0+2=2; similarly "asdasd 098675asas"  would match because when n is 2, the 2*2+2 = 6 and the string has 6 numbers. Sorry for any clumsy language!

Comment: @Klaimmore Thanks for your post and swift response; it triggered thinking that got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is any integer then `2n+2` is an even number, then you could do:

```
-?[0-9]*[02468]!/g
```

where `-?` accounts for negative numbers. I assume the string ends with `!`.

Comment: I think OP wants 2n+2 *digits*

Answer (score 0):

> I'm new to Regex; is it possible to develop an expression that will
>   match strings that has a list of adjacent numbers (that don't have to
>   be ordered) where the count of the numbers equals the expression 2n+2?
>   So " asdasd 02" would match because when n is 0, 2*0+2=2; similarly
>   "asdasd 098675asas" would match because when n is 2, the 2*2+2 = 6 and
>   the string has 6 numbers. Sorry for any clumsy language!

Yes, it is as simple as `(\d\d)+` the details of how to use the regex would depend on the language itself. But all you need to match is *pairs of digits*.